# Static resource mapping in Spring3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, spring-3, static-resource

My project is implemented in Spring3 and configuration is almost xml.
Configuration of static resource mapping is like below:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/a/**" location="file:/data/a/"/>
```

There is no problem when accessing /a/xxx.jpg but 404 Error is occurred when accessing subdirectory like /a/b/yyy.jpg. There is no problem about access authority of filesystem. How can I solve this problem? Additional configuration is needed?

(Add) Project directory is fine, but filesystem directory does not work

Answer (score 0):

Use something like below :

```
<mvc:resources location="/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

You can specify classpath also to location any particular folder like below.

```
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

Comment: Project directory is fine, but filesystem directory does not work

Comment: where is the directory actually?

Comment: Web server's filesystem